Wald theorem 8.1.2 and the proceeding corollary
I am currently confused on the corollary of theorem 8.1.2 in Wald's book, specifically the paragraph separating the two. I've attached a screenshot below.

Why does Wald say that using theorem 8.1.2 we can deform the curve $\lambda$ into a timelike curve as opposed to saying we can deform it into a timelike geodesic? Surely the former doesn't actually follow from 8.1.2? On the other hand, if we could deform the curve to a timelike geodesic in every convex normal neighbourhood, would it not then follow that the timelike curve we've constructed is also a timelike geodesic (as the choice of convex normal neighbourhood is non-unique)?
